# is there a way to use java component.vue ------------ cli and java npm

Tags: java, vue.js, vue-cli

i've a component.vue made with @vue-cli and i use java sdk in the background.js file but i need use in the App.vue and his childs

i try this, but doesnt work
in the main background.js works perfectly

component.vue

```
<template>
<div>hola</div>
<template>

<script>
import java from 'java';
/*
  var javaInit = require('./javaInit');
  var java = javaInit.getJavaInstance();
  */
 var javaLangSystem = java.import('java.lang.System');
    var n="message from appvue";
    javaLangSystem.out.printlnSync(n);
</script>
```

is there a way to use it??

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. While it is probably in some way possible to access Java from JavaScript, it's unlikely that would be possible in a browser. Also, what is "background.js"?

Comment: It's vue with electrón and node

Comment: That information doesn't really help. None of those things have anything to do with Java.

Comment: In npm You can use java, using the npm-java plugin, and i use it but in this time i need use them un a Child component but doesnt work i leave the sample un the post